# Easiest way to sell stuff and track inventory

Tags: e-commerce, paypal, payment, inventory

on my website I sell unique items. I have programmed it so that on the selling page, users can select any amount of these items, and it calculates the cost. The key is that I only have 1 of each of these items. So I need the shopping cart system to not allow the payment to go through unless it is available.

I've been searching for a good quick/easy/cheap solution and can't find one. I don't expect this site to make a lot of money (the transactions are a few bucks), so I didn't want to need a ssl certificate.

The only way I know of not needing an ssl certificate would be to use paypal or google checkout. However, I do not think there is a way of using these services and making paypal's server run a script to check how many are available on the site. Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: "searching for a [] solution" - does that mean you wanted to use a pre-made shopping cart system or you were looking for logic to help you out?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about it more, and I think the problem is that once the user gets to the paypal payment screen, I have no control. I guess I could do something like they click the buy it now link, a php script updates it to sold, then they go to the paypal screen, but then they might not continue the purchase...

Comment: Sounds like you need a "pending" status.

Comment: Ya, but if I set the status to pending when they click buy, they could never complete the transaction. I'd have to do something where it records the time they thought they might like to buy it. It's not fool proof. I think I've decided on a pretty good system where if it accidentally oversells an item, they get another one.


Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please share your solution / system with us here, so that others can find it when they have a similar problem and do a search on SO.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PayPal Website Payments Standard (using a cart rather than 'Buy Now' Buttons) then you could use IPN or PDT (see the paypal docs [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_documentation#wps)) to get PayPal to call back to you with the status of the payment.

The work flow would then be to set status to reserved when the item is added to the cart, and then wait for the IPN/PDT call to come back with the payment status, and mark the item as sold.

You would still need to check and reset to available any item that had been reserved for longer than say 2 Hours. (You could do this before serving a page to a user so that they have the latest availability and you don't need a cron job or long running process)

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide a little more information about how you have implemented ur shopping card, it would have been more easier for other to assist! If you are using any ecommerce solution then it should be there already in the track inventory section. But Provided that you have implemented d shopping cart manually, why don't you add little bit of codes that checks the inventory status first before letting your customers check out?